# How to do a function to generate a rank/score number?

Tags: python, math

I need to do a function that generate a rank number(integer) based in N parameter received in that function. Each number need to be the same order of magnitude of that parameters, compare numbers of the same field and when the numbers of the same field tie than use second field to deadlock, e.g:

```
func({'field1': 100, 'field2': 3500225})
func({'field1': 50, 'field2': 5465481362135)
```

The number generated by the first function must be higher than the second because 100 is greater than 50.

```
func({'field1': 100, 'field2': 3500225})
func({'field1': 100, 'field2': 5465481362135)
```

The number generated by the second function must be higher than the first because field1 is tie than to deadloack it need to use the second field, so 5465481362135 is greater than 3500225.

```
func({'field1': 100, 'field2': 3500225})
func({'field1': 100, 'field2': 3500225, 'field3': 5465481362135, ...N})
```

In the sample above the second function need to be higher than the first because the first call function doesn't have the field3 so we can set their value to zero. Note that we can have N fields.

I have tried this code bellow but the value after the dot isn't right because a simple sum doesn't consider the priority of fields.:

```
Config = [
    {'id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'Description': 'root', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'parent_id': 1, 'Description': 'PF', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 3, 'parent_id': 1, 'Description': 'FP', 'level': 2},
    {'id': 4, 'parent_id': 2, 'Description': 'Bank', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 5, 'parent_id': 2, 'Description': 'Input', 'level': 2},
    {'id': 6, 'parent_id': 4, 'Description': 'ST', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 7, 'parent_id': 4, 'Description': 'CF', 'level': 2},
    {'id': 8, 'parent_id': 4, 'Description': 'BB', 'level': 3},
    {'id': 9, 'parent_id': 5, 'Description': 'DDS', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 10, 'parent_id': 5, 'Description': 'Col', 'level': 2},
    {'id': 11, 'parent_id': 3, 'Description': 'Qtd.Event', 'level': 1},
    {'id': 12, 'parent_id': 3, 'Description': 'Unix_Date', 'level': 2},
]


def hierarchy_field(field):
    if field[0]['parent_id'] is None:
        return field
    else:
        [field.append(x) for x in hierarchy_field([dic for dic in Config if dic['id'] == field[0]['parent_id']])]
    return field


def calc_priority(fields):
    for field in [dic for dic in Config if dic['Description'] in [x for x in fields]]:
        score_level = sum(x['level'] for x in hierarchy_field([field]))*-1
        score_level += score_level
    score_value = sum(fields.values())
    score = str(score_level)+'.'+str(score_value)
    return score
    #     dic[field['Description']] = score_level
    # return sorted(dic, reverse=True)


value = calc_priority({'Qtd.Event': 871, 'Unix_Date': 564645})
print(value)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems straight-forward using `sorted` with the `key` argument set to a custom sort function.

Comment: @CoryKramer isn't a simple sort, I need to generate a rank/score number guided by their field priority and value, take a look in the code.